# не загружается js на страницу

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Скрипт не подключается когда я использую данный код

**show.html.erb**

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'comments' %>
<% end %>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @link.title %><br>
  <strong>Url:</strong>
  <%= @link.url %><br>
  <strong>User:</strong>
  <%= @link.user.email %><br>
</p>
<%-if user_signed_in?%>
  <%= render 'comments/new', review: Comment.new(link_id: @link.id) %>
<%-end%>

<%= render 'comments/show', comments: @comments %>
```

В консоли запросов видно что он должен был загрузиться, но его нет...

Название скрипта **comments.js**

[image] 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только перезагрузка страницы помогает или вставка **js** кода в тег **script**

Может кто уже сталкивался с такой проблемой.Спасибо за ответ)

Comment: я уже решил данный  вопрос все дело в том что он не хочет загружаться из-за **turbolinks**. https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#running-javascript-when-a-page-loads

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятен твой подход или вопрос описан не полностью. Напиши код на руби и отправляй запросы в базу через ajax. Код javascript размещай в папке **assets/javascript/**. rails их все загрузит автоматом.

Зачем тебе такой код?

```
if user_signed_in?
  = render 'comments/new', review: Comment.new(link_id: @link.id)
end
```

Зачем нагружать рельсы и гонять данные по вебу. Создай просто формочку и если придут данные создавай **Comment.new**. Старайся держать вьюхи в чистоте.
Создавать объекты класса лучше в контроллере. Не нарушай MVC!

Comment: так дело в том что жс здесь размещен assets/javascript/ но он не загружается с 1 раза только если жму перезагрузить на данной вью